# Debian, re-install base installation after wrong remove of packages

Tags: debian

How can I repair installation to it's base working state. Currently my system booting to terminal. Is it possible to re-install missing packages online?

Answer (score 0):

If you were using default xfce desktop:

```
sudo tasksel install xfce-desktop
```